# Lucene NRT - opening a new IndexReader after every commit?

Tags: java, lucene

I need my results in Lucene to be available immediately after adding a document. Everything I read says I should be caching the IndexSearcher instances, but I don't see how I can achieve what I want without reopening the IndexReader on every write and therefore the IndexSearcher too...

What am I doing wrong?

```
class LuceneStorage {

    private final Directory luceneDirectory;
    private final IndexWriter indexWriter;

    private volatile DirectoryReader indexReader;

    LuceneStorage() {
        try {
            this.luceneDirectory = NIOFSDirectory.open(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")).resolve("lucene"));

            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new KeywordAnalyzer());
            config.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

            this.indexWriter = new IndexWriter(luceneDirectory, config);
            this.indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    public Stream<String> read(String id) {
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
        QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("id", new KeywordAnalyzer());
        StreamableSimpleCollector collector = new StreamableSimpleCollector();

        try {
            indexSearcher.search(queryParser.parse(id), collector);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        IntStream docIds = collector.stream();

        return docIds.mapToObj(i -> {
                try {
                    return indexSearcher.doc(i).get("content");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            });
    }

    public String write(String content, String... ids) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new StringField("id", uuid, Field.Store.YES));

        Stream.of(ids)
            .forEach(i -> document.add(new StringField("id", i, Field.Store.YES)));

        document.add(new StoredField("content", content));

        try {
            indexWriter.addDocument(document);
            indexReader = DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(indexReader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }

        return uuid;
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of those admonitions is that you don't open a new `IndexReader` for *every query*.  You do need to reopen after writing to make changes available.  Creating a new `IndexSearcher` isn't particularly costly.  It's opening the `IndexReader` that is the expensive part.

Comment: @femtoRgon I guess, in order to meet my requirements, I have to open an `IndexReader` after every document is added.

Comment: One option you do have, which might be helpful on performance, you can use [`openIfChanged(DirectoryReader oldReader, IndexWriter writer, boolean applyAllDeletes)`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#openIfChanged(org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader,%20org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter,%20boolean)), which allows you to search uncommitted changes (that is without closing or commiting the writer).

Comment: @femtoRgon - am I not doing that already?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, doesn't look like it.  I believe you'd need to pass the writer to the method in order to make the uncommitted changes available.

Comment: Check out [ControlledRealTimeReopenThread](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ControlledRealTimeReopenThread.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is not designed to provide realtime search results. So if this is really a requirement, you should be looking at something else.

However Lucene can provide *near* realtime search results, so your users would have to wait at most eg. 1 second before changes are made searchable. The way to do it would be to use a SearcherManager (http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/SearcherManager.html) and have a background thread that periodically refreshes the current index reader.